# Python select one character after space

Tags: python

Example, I have a field of names like 'Smith Joe' and I need a python statement to select 'Smith J'.  I can get everything up to the space using the following:

```
x = 'Smith Joe'
x[:x.rindex(' ')]
'Smith'
```

Comment: Just add 2 to the index?

Comment: You can just increase the index by 2?

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 'Smith Joe'
x[:x.rindex(' ') + 2]
```

Which gives

```
Smith J
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 x = 'Smith Joe'
 x[:x.rindex(' ') + 2 ]
'Smith J'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = 'Smith Joe'
x[:x.rindex(' ') + 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just increment the :x.rindex(' ') by 2, which would include the first character after the space?

```
x[:x.rindex(' ') + 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be tempted to do something like:

```
import re

x = 'Smith Joe'
print re.match('\w+\s\w', x).group()
# Smith J
```

This'll enable easier tweaking for grouping and formatting, eg:

```
m = re.match('(\w+)\s(\w)', x)
print 'Mr. {1} {0}'.format(*m.groups())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 'Smith Joe'.split()
y = x[0] + " "+ x[1][0]

a = 'Smith Joe King Cole'.split()
b = x[0]+" "+" ".join([t[0] for t in x[1:])
```